# I am only receiving 0s from my Entry widget Tkinter (idle 3.5)

Tags: python, tkinter

Please excuse me if i have done anything really dumb here, i am quite new to python and programming in general

```
window=Tk()
window.configure(background="red")
window.title("DOD")
window.geometry("600x400")

name=StringVar()
race=IntVar()

def callback3():
    print(race.get())
def callback2():
    lbl1.configure(text="Hello {}, What race do you want to be? \n            1.Human 2.Elf or 3. Dwarf".format(name.get()))
    print (name.get())
    Race=Entry(window, textvariable=race,bg='tomato')
    btn1.configure(command=callback3)
def callback1():
    lbl1.configure(text="What is your name?")
    Name=Entry(window, textvariable=name,bg='tomato')
    Name.pack()
    btn1.configure(command=callback2)

lbl1=Label(window, text="Welcome to...", bg="red")
lbl1.pack()
Photo1=PhotoImage(file="/Users/Owen/Downloads/DOD.gif")
image1=Label(window, image=Photo1)
image1.pack()
btn1=Button(window, text="Continue", command=callback1)
btn1.pack()
```

no matter what number i put in for the race selection i just see:
0
0
0
0
in the shell (due to me printing the input)
i have been speculating that this is all because of it being the wrong Entry, but i can't seem to delete the old one (Entry thing) and replace it with a new one.   Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You don't have a window.mainloop() and you don't pack() the "Race" Entry widget so it never shows on the screen.  I assume you are trying to key into the "Name" widget a second time, so of course the Race widget has nothing/zero in it.  If you want, print name.get() in callback3 as well to verify this.

Comment: Thank you good sir for pointing those out (It works now). And i think i did imply that it was probably something dumb. but thank you to everyone for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skimming [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) it seems to me that binding to an IntVar may not work. Could you try using a StringVar and converting the result to an integer, something along these lines:

```
race = StringVar()
...
print int(race.get())
```

And if that's acceptable then you could subclass StringVar to make it prettier.